# How to run write an append query in SQL using an IIF statement to truncate the length of a field

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a syntax issue with the following SQL routine which aims to append records to a table and adjust the field 'tblMasterListOfEventsHistoryNotes' to 25 charachters.

```
st_sql = "INSERT INTO tblSearchEngine08 ( [ID Event], Event, Commitment, Type, Description, tblMasterListOfEventsHistoryNotes, Query01OpenItems, Query02DateSelect, Query03ProjectSelect, Query04PrioritySelect, Query06ContactSelect, Query07ParolaChiaveSelect )" & _
"SELECT tblSearchEngine01.[ID Event], tblSearchEngine01.Event, tblSearchEngine01.Commitment, tblSearchEngine01.Type, tblSearchEngine01.Description, IIf(Len([tblMasterListOfEventsHistoryNotes])>25,Left([tblMasterListOfEventsHistoryNotes],25) & '.....',[tblMasterListOfEventsHistoryNotes]) AS X, tblSearchEngine01.Query01OpenItems, tblSearchEngine01.Query02DateSelect, tblSearchEngine01.Query03ProjectSelect, tblSearchEngine01.Query04PrioritySelect, tblSearchEngine01.Query06ContactSelect, tblSearchEngine01.Query07ParolaChiaveSelect" & _
"FROM tblSearchEngine01 WHERE (((tblSearchEngine01.Query01OpenItems)='1') AND ((tblSearchEngine01.Query02DateSelect)='1') AND ((tblSearchEngine01.Query03ProjectSelect)='1') AND ((tblSearchEngine01.Query04PrioritySelect)='1') AND ((tblSearchEngine01.Query06ContactSelect)='1') AND ((tblSearchEngine01.Query07ParolaChiaveSelect)='1'))"
Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 st_sql = "INSERT INTO tblSearchEngine08 ( [ID Event], [Event], [Commitment], [Type], [Description], [tblMasterListOfEventsHistoryNotes], [Query01OpenItems], [Query02DateSelect], [Query03ProjectSelect], [Query04PrioritySelect], [Query06ContactSelect], [Query07ParolaChiaveSelect])" & _
"SELECT [tblSearchEngine01].[ID Event], [tblSearchEngine01].[Event], [tblSearchEngine01].[Commitment], [tblSearchEngine01].[Type], [tblSearchEngine01].[Description], IIf(Len([tblMasterListOfEventsHistoryNotes])>300,Left([tblMasterListOfEventsHistoryNotes],300) & '...',[tblMasterListOfEventsHistoryNotes]) AS [tblMasterListOfEventsHistoryNotesx], [tblSearchEngine01].[Query01OpenItems], [tblSearchEngine01].[Query02DateSelect], [tblSearchEngine01].[Query03ProjectSelect], [tblSearchEngine01].[Query04PrioritySelect], [tblSearchEngine01].[Query06ContactSelect], [tblSearchEngine01].[Query07ParolaChiaveSelect]" & _
"FROM [tblSearchEngine01] WHERE ((([tblSearchEngine01].[Query01OpenItems])='1') AND (([tblSearchEngine01].[Query02DateSelect])='1') AND (([tblSearchEngine01].[Query03ProjectSelect])='1') AND (([tblSearchEngine01].[Query04PrioritySelect])='1') AND (([tblSearchEngine01].[Query06ContactSelect])='1') AND (([tblSearchEngine01].[Query07ParolaChiaveSelect])='1'))"

 Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)
```

Comment: It works fine Hans.  It queries the values from a table taking only the values where the last six fields have a '1' value in it and pastes it into another table.  In the event that the field 'tblMasterListOfEventsHistoryNotes' is Greater than 25 charachters, the query takes the first 25 characthers and adds '.....' at the end (thanks for the help).